# Angular 2 Auth Gaurd using ngrx store select. Do i unsubscribe?

Tags: angular, observable, ngrx, unsubscribe

I use the async pipe in my templates for all store select values as it does all the clean up, including unsubscribing, on its own.

But when i manually subscribe to a value in my auth gaurd, would i need to unsubscribe this? If yes, then what would be the best way to do that?

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGaurd implements CanActivate{

constructor(
    private store: Store<fromRoot.State>,
    private router: Router
){}

canActivate(){
    this.store.select(getLoggedInState).subscribe(res => {
        if(res){
            return true
        }else {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }
    });
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: you didn't unsubscribe and what is that you are trying to do?

Comment: @Aravind Where do i unsubscribe? Where would the unsubscribe line go?

Comment: You shouldn't be subscribing in your guard, try something like comment on github. https://github.com/ngrx/store/issues/270#issuecomment-260845982

Comment: @Adam Thanks!! This is great!

Comment: That doesn't mean you can down vote the post

Comment: @Aravind That wasn't me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `take` to get just the first value:

```
canActivate(){
    this.store.select(getLoggedInState).take(1).subscribe(res => {
        if(res){
            return true
        }else {
           c this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }
    });
        return false;
    }
}
```

`take(n)` makes the observable take the first `n` values it receives and then complete. You would not need to unsubscribe in this case.